# Can I move my Kerbals inside a pod?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

How can I move my Kerbals inside the Lander-can, Hitchhiker, or Command pod? If it isn't possible by default, is there a mod allowing me to do that?

Comment: Voting to reopen as per the meta posts, [Is “mod rec” really an umbrella category that we want to use?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/6828/4797) and [Closed 'mod recommendation' Skyrim question - Can this question be improved and then reopened?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5547/4797)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a mod recommendation. See the [latest meta post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8147/the-community-is-closing-mod-rec-questions) on the subject for the most recent community consensus.

Comment: I don't think that using a ~1 day old answer on a question that proposes that this question should be open is "community consensus".

Answer (score 6):

It is currently not possible to control and move the Kerbals inside the pods.

Because of the way the game handles the interior scene, it is also very complicated to override the existing behaviour - there are no mods that fulfill this purpose, and there don't appear to be any plans for this in the future - neither in the game itself, nor in any announced plugins.

Answer (score 1):

As of 0.25 (October 7, 2014), you can perform a [crew transfer](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/0.25#Crew_Transfer) by clicking the crew hatch and then "Transfer".